# appending images to DOM only works sometimes

Tags: javascript

I'm putting some images on a page like this.

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper"),
    urls = [/*array of URLs*/],
    el;

for (var i = 0; i <= urls.length; i++){
    el = document.createElement("img");
    el.src = urls[i];
    wrapper.appendChild(el);
}
```

It works only sometimes. Some images fail to load. Is there any reason why this would be? Do I need to defer execution of the next iteration of the loop until the current image is fully downloaded?

### EDIT:

[THIS](http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/14700000/So-cute-puppies-14749028-1600-1200.jpg) is the evil image in question.

Comment: You have a pretty obvious syntax error in your code, which I hope doesn't exist in your actual page. What is `urls[[i]'` actually supposed to be?

Comment: @meagar yeah, there were some typos.

Comment: @thomas - still a typo.  Should be `el.src = urls[i];`

Comment: Your link is not to a static image - it redirects to a live page.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yeah, it's an image hosted on some site. Isn't that static enough? What's the difference?

Comment: When I try to follow the link, it does not show me an image.  It redirects to a web page.

Comment: @jfriend00 That redirect must be the issue. Thanks for pointing that out! When I pulled it from google images, they must somehow get around the redirect. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to wait until an image is loaded before loading the next image.

You have several typos in the code in your question.  These two lines should be:

```
el.src = urls[i];
wrapper.appendChild(el);
```

---

On the page link you provided, I don't see any obvious places in that page where some images aren't loading.  Can you be more specific about what isn't loading in that page?

---

The only issues I can think of that would cause some images not to load:

1. You have a script error that stops your script from running before it completes.
2. Some of your images URLs are incorrect or point to things that are not actually images.
3. The web server serving those images has some issue
4. There's some sort of intermittent networking/internet issue from the location where you are doing your testing.
5. There's a browser plugin (often security or privacy related) that is interfering with the loading of the images.

Comment: The page is just a link to an image. That's an image that's not loading on my page.

Comment: @thomas - the link you have may look like an image link, but when I follow it, it redirects to an actual live page, not a static image.  Besides, we would need to see the actual code on the actual page that has the problem, not just a screenshot.